# How to register a failed Mocha test on a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, chai

I am writing Javascript Mocha unit tests on code that returns promises. I am using the [Chai as Promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised) library. I expect the following minimal unit test to fail.

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

var Promise = require("bluebird");

describe('2+2', function () {
    var four = Promise.resolve(2 + 2);
    it('should equal 5', function () {
        four.should.eventually.equal(5);
    })
});
```

When I run this test, I see an assertion error printed to the console, but the test still counts as passing.

```
> mocha test/spec.js 


  2+2
    ✓ should equal 5 
Unhandled rejection AssertionError: expected 4 to equal 5


  1 passing (10ms)
```

How do I write this test so that a failed assertion causes the test to count as a failure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I needed to return the result of assertion. This test fails as expected.

```
    it('should equal 5', function () {
        return four.should.eventually.equal(5);
    })
```

Comment: Use `Promise.all` to combine multiple assertions.

Answer (score 23):

For anybody else having trouble with failed assertions not failing unit tests with promises, I learned that you should NOT pass `done` to the function. Instead, just return the promise:

```
it('should handle promises', function(/*no done here*/) {

    return promiseFunction().then(function(data) {
        // Add your assertions here
    });

    // No need to catch anything in the latest version of Mocha;
    // Mocha knows how to handle promises and will see it rejected on failure

});
```

[This article](http://paulsalaets.com/testing-with-promises-in-mocha) pointed me in the right direction.  Good luck!

Comment: Best answer in the universe ever.  Well, OK, you can see I'm wrestling against my JavaScript ignorance a fair bit lately -- but on the plus side, it makes me grateful for small favors. :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @piercebot answer, I am using [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised) to resolve the promise like this:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised); 

...

it('should handle promises', function() {    
  return promiseFunction().then(function(res) {
    expect(Promise.resolve(res)).to.eventually.equals(true);
  });
});
```